When does the map from Fundamental Group to Holonomy Group Injective?
We know that over a rank $n$ vector bundle $E$ (with base space being $M$, a manifold), if the connection $\nabla$ is flat, then the parallel transport along loop $\gamma:I\to M$ for $E$ will only depend on the homotopy class of $\gamma$. Thus one is able to construct a surjective map $\varphi:\pi_1(M)\to \text{Hol}_x(E)$ for base point $x\in M$.
My question is, under what condition will this map $\varphi$ also be injective?
I'll be grateful if someone can give me some theorems, references or anything related.

PS: I'm from physical background, and I'm considering if the fundamental group of a gauge group $G$ isomorphic to the collection of "large gauge transformations".

I am afraid, the answer will disappoint you: It is injective when it is injective. With every representation $\pi_1(M)\to GL(n, F)$ one associates a flat bundle with the holonomy $F$. If you happen to find an injective representation, your holonomy will be injective. In few  cases, one can argue that "generic" representations $\rho$ are injective...

Great question, I don't really have any ideas -- if the bundle is trivial, for example, the map is far from injective, so it has to do with the fact that your bundle is really twisted around all of $M$ (maybe this heuristic could be made precise by thinking bundles coming from covering spaces). This action is often called the monodromy action when the connection is flat, and you might have better luck googling that specific term than holonomy.

Thank you @MoisheKohan. I get the point that for any representation $\rho$ there is exactly one flat bundle corresponding to $\rho$. Is this result stated as some theorem?

It is a very special case of the associated bundle construction, you will find it for instance in Steenrod's book "Topology of Fiber Bundles." But it is not really a theorem but a rather trivial construction.

Here is the construction. Let $F$ be your field (say, complex or real numbers), $\rho: \pi_1(M)\to G= GL(n,F)$ a representation. Let $V=F^n$, the $n$-dimensional vector space over $F$. Let $\tilde M\to M$ denote the universal cover of $M$. The fundamental group $\Gamma$ of $M$ acts by diffeomorphisms on $\tilde M$ "nicely" so that $M$ is diffeomorphic to the quotient $\tilde M/\Gamma$. Now, consider the "diagonal" action of $\Gamma$ on $\tilde M\times V$,
$$
\gamma(x,v)=(\gamma x, \rho(\gamma)v).
$$
The product $\tilde E=\tilde M\times V$ is a trivial vector bundle over $\tilde M$; let's equip it with the trivial (flat) connection $\tilde\nabla$. The action of $\Gamma$ on $\tilde E$ preserves the bundle structure and the connection. Take the quotient $\tilde E/\Gamma=E$. The projection $\tilde E\to \tilde M$ descends to a projection $E\to M$, which is a rank $n$ vector bundle over $M$. The connection $\tilde\nabla$ descends to a flat connection $\nabla$ on $E\to M$. The holonomy of $\nabla$ is $\rho$.
Note that, sometimes, the bundle $E\to M$ is trivial as a vector bundle, while $\rho$ is injective. The simplest example is when $M=S^1$, $F={\mathbb C}$, $\Gamma=\mathbb Z$, and $\rho: \Gamma\to GL(1,F)$ is an injective representation.
